# How to set Raycast direction to 90 degrees instead of through camera

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, 3d

I have a problem with my 3D Project. It is quite complicated to describe the purpose so I try to abstract it to the minimum.
I have an live videostream of the unity program which I bring up to fullscreen (1920 x 1200). One user clicks on the screen to send the coords to the unity app.

sending coords:

```
// relative coord
float x = mouse_x / 1920.0f;
float y = mouse_y / 1200.0f;
```

The receiver is the unity app, which trys to make an 3D coordinate of it and finds a wall or an obstacle to place a mark.

```
1. Attempt
// 1268 x 720 receiver viewport size
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Position.x * 1268.0f, Position.y * 720.0f, 0));

2. Attempt

// * 1268 not necessary
Vector3 far = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(fix.Position.x, fix.Position.y, 1));

Vector3 near = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(fix.Position.x, fix.Position.y, 0));

Vector3 dir = far - near;
dir.Normalize();

Ray ray = new Ray(near, dir);

RaycastHit hitInfo;

if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
{
// place mark
}
```

[image]

Both attempts results in the same way. If the coordinate is around the center then it is in the center on the receiver as well. But the more it goes to the edge it will be much farer from the position it should be. The picture shows what I think happens. The red circle is the current behaviour and the green is what I was expecting. I'd rather have a 90 degrees ray from the screen to the wall than right through the cam.
I really do not know what to do. Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: The viewport is not a *physical spatial* entity, so that diagram you have is confusing. You need to specify a *projection plane* distance, which is the perpendicular distance from the camera position to the plane from. which you want rays to start

Answer (score 1):

You're right about your drawing, this is indeed what's happening.

Here is a test I did using `Debug.DrawRay`.
[image]

The blue ray is the output of this code.

```
Debug.DrawRay(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward * 100f, Color.red);
```

And here is the drawing of the red, like you did.

```
var viewportPointRay = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(viewportTouchPos);
Debug.DrawRay(viewportPointRay.origin, viewportPointRay.direction * 3f, Color.blue);
```

I was expecting a truly simple answer but I wasn't able to find one. I did found a trick to do what you want though.

```
var ray = new Ray(viewportPointRay.origin, Camera.main.transform.forward);
Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction, Color.green);
```

Result
[image]